# How to add custom notification in iOS Custom Keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I have added Custom Keyboard extension inside my app and running perfect.

I have added `NSNotification` in my keyboard extension class like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeKeyboardColor) name:@"keyboard_color"  object:nil];
```

Now I am calling this notification from my view controller class like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"keyboard_color" object:self];
```

Now I have added my notification selector method in my keyboard extension class like this:

```
-(void)changeKeyboardColor{
}
```

But it is not working. I am testing in simulator and I don't know How to test keyboard extension in simulator.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults for passing value between app and extension.

Answer (score 2):

Create App Group from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/)

[image]

Group name must be like group.XXXXX

Enable App Group if it's disable for both app id and extension app id.

[image]

Update to existing provisioning profiles if it's look Invalid!

Go to Target and mention group name which you have created

[image]

Go to Keyboard extension and mention same group name

[image]

Now you done with all required settings.

In your project store value in NSUserDefaults

```
 let userd: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.XXXXX")!
 userd.setObject("test11", forKey: "key")
 userd.synchronize()
```

//Objective-C

```
NSUserDefaults *userd = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.XXXXX"];
[userd setObject:@"test11" forKey:@"key"];//set the object you want to share
[userd synchronize];
```

For retrieving NSUserDefaults value in Extension class

```
 let userd: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.XXXXX")!
 print(userd.objectForKey("key"))
```

// Objective-C

```
NSUserDefaults *userd = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.XXXXX"];
NSLog(@"%@",[userd objectForKey:@"key"]);
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: are you using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: It should be work. Something is missing in settings. It's work for me!

Comment: I am using 7.0 version

Comment: But I think it's not because of Xcode version. Check all settings again.

Comment: I checked multiple times. Not working... There is no problem in settings. I think problem is how to run extension in simulator

Comment: I have check in Simulator as well. Work perfect!

Comment: run extension in iPhone 6 Plus Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The method for a notification should take a single parameter, the triggering notification:

```
-(void)changeKeyboardColorNotice: (NSNotification *) theNotice
{
  NSLog(@"In %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

And you need to add a colon to the selector:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
  selector: @selector(changeKeyboardColorNotice:) 
  name: @"keyboard_color"  
  object: nil];
```

Comment: Can We test this in iOS Simulator ?

Comment: I changed code like what you told. but I am not able to test in simulator. If I run Keyboard extension then I am able to run project and If I run project then I am not able to run Keyboard extension