# How to call main container app method from extension keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, call, custom-keyboard

Is there any way to call `container app` method from `extension keyboard`?

I tried by using following NSNotificationCenter, But still its not working.

I have added NSNotificationCenter and method into my main container app.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(method),
        name: "methodClicked",
        object: nil)

func method(){
    //doing stuff
}
```

and in my `app extension keyboard` I'm checking if container app is currently visible then post that notification `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("methodClicked", object: nil)`

Please post answer in `Objective-c or Swift` if anyone know proper way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer. You can't send notification to container app
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411165/how-to-add-custom-notification-in-ios-custom-keyboard/35428839#35428839

Comment: @kb920 Yes this i know, we can share data through App Group. But actually my requirement is if I click on specific key from keyboard extension then I want to show UIAlertView into my container app.

Comment: @SunilTarge Did you got any solution?

Comment: @ParthPatel I guess the solution is only we can share data through App Group. Answer this question, If you could find any other precise way to do that. thx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing and realized (for now) that the only way to make an extension call a function on it's containing app is via remote server.
that means when an event on the extension occur you can make a call to your remote server that will notify your app (using notification).

Probably an overkill but it should work.